# Regex counting string characters using Match

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if the `string` contains exactly 5 characters. If so I need to return true.

```
string name = "Perry";
```

I need to only use regex here.

```
 var re = Regex.Match(name, "^.{1,5}$");
```

However, this returns true if the characters are in range 1 and 5. What I expect is for the result to return true only if it contains 5 characters. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^.{1,5}$` mean your string can contains from 1 to 5 char. You can use `^.{5}$` for exactly 5 chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.IsMatch("Perry", "^.{5}$");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can simply do this:

```
string name = "Perry";
if(name.Length == 5)
```

`.{5}` will match any character of 5 length. If you only want alphanumeric characters, then can use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$
```

Comment: OP explicit said `only use regex here`

Answer (score 0):

> What I expect is for the result to return true only if it contains 5 characters.

But which characters are valid? Is `\n` a valid character here?
If yes; then use a regex like `^[\S\s]{5}$` instead

```
^         asserts position at start of the string
[\S\s]    matches any whitespace or non-whitespace character 
{5}       matches exactly 5 times
$         asserts position at the end of the string
```

Some other options those may make sense are:

> ```
> .       matches any character (except for line terminators) ([\r\f\v] are also valid here)   
> \w      matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) -> recommended
> \S      matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
> ```